# Can't Connect Python Flask With PSQL Database

Tags: python, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, web-development-server

every time i try to make connection between python and PSQL this error disappear ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to provide more context. What exactly do you mean by "trying to make a connection"? Which libraries are you using? Maybe share some snippet of your code.

Comment: @slashCoder i'm using sqlalchemy in flask

Comment: @slashCoder i've just uploaded my code, u can see

Comment: Please provide your `DATABASE_URL`.

Comment: Your code relies on an environment variable named `DATABASE_URL` that is used in line 6 to establish the connection with the DB. It seems that either you don't have it defined or it has the wrong value. Try replacing that with a valid URL directly as a string literal first to confirm that's the issue and then you might deal with how to specify that in a more flexible way if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first make sure your DATABASE_URL has been defined before you even run your server. If you are using an online database and have a url, executing the command in terminal (for mac/linux):

```
    export DATABASE_URL = "https://my_database_link"
```

inside your virtual environment, where you installed python will connect your virtual environment variable to your database online. If you are still experiencing problems. make sure you have installed everything correctly.